# How to play Haydn Variation trills

Tags: trills

In Haydn's F minor variations for piano, how does one attack the continuous trills, one note after the other?

Comment: The 6 means the same it always does: "These notes must be shortened so that there are 6 of them to one beat rather than 4."

Comment: Are you asking about Haydn or Beethoven?

Comment: Haydn! there is a variation that has nothing but a continuous set of trills in the right hand.

Comment: For longer trills use 123231... or 32313231...

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you mean this part of Hob.XVII:6. This is from the Edition Peters score.

[image: score of Hob.XVII:6, bars 81-88]

I think that the extension of the trill notation throughout the whole bar is simply a convenience to avoid having to write **tr~~~tr~~~tr~~~tr~~~**; it should be played simply as a succession of trills. Although what's going on with the fingering in bar 86, I have no idea.